# AngularJS + Directive: Multiple Transcluded Elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm trying to add a body directive which will have a left panel and a right panel. But in between these panels I will have some content that is private to the body directive. I'm currently using **transclude=true** option to load the content. But, I'm looking for a way to use two ng-transclude. I investigated a lot how to solve that, but I was not able to find an elegant solution. I had to manually add the transcluded objects in the compile step of the body directive. Following is the way I solved that:

**Body Directive**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('body', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'body.html',
        compile: function compile(element, attrs, transclude) {
            return function (scope) {
                transclude(scope.$parent, function (clone) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < clone.length; i++){ 
                       var el = $(clone[i]);
                       if(el.attr('panel-left') !== undefined) {
                            element.find('#firstPanel').html(el);
                       } else if(el.attr('panel-right') !== undefined) {
                            element.find('#secondPanel').html(el);
                       }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive('panelLeft', function () {
    return {
        require: "^body",
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
    };
});

myApp.directive('panelRight', function () {
    return {
        require: "^body",
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
    };
});
```

**Template**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="body.html">
    <h1> {{title}} </h1>
    <hr/>

    <div id="firstPanel" class="inner-panel"></div>
    <div id="innerMiddleContent" class="inner-panel">middle private content here</div>
    <div id="secondPanel" class="inner-panel"></div>
</script>

<div body title="Sample Body Directive">
    <div panel-left>
        Public content that goes on the left
    </div>   

    <div panel-right>
        Public content that goes on the right
    </div>    
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/alansouzati/wegyc7cv/) is the JSFiddle for this example. I'm looking for something like this:

**Good-to-have Template**

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="body.html">
     <h1> {{title}} </h1>
     <hr/>

     <div id="firstPanel" class="inner-panel" ng-transclude="panel-left"></div>
     <div id="innerMiddleContent" class="inner-panel">middle private content here</div>
     <div id="secondPanel" class="inner-panel" ng-transclude="panel-right"></div>
 </script>
```

**Question**: Am I doing something wrong? Is there a recommended way to solve this issue?

Comment: I think you are on the right way, the `ng-transclude` doesn't support splitting transcluded elements to multiple places. BTW, the `transclude` function in `compile:` has been deprecated. You should use the `transclude` function in `link:` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for letting my know that transclude in compile is deprecated. But my question is more if it makes sense to have this multiple ng-transclude integrated in next versions of Angular. Sorry, I should have made myself more clear.

Comment: Sound like a good idea! May be you could write an enhanced version of `ng-transclude` to use in your project first.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. I will try to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen this directive?

https://github.com/zachsnow/ng-multi-transclude

I think this is exactly what you are looking for.

So with slight modifications to your template

```
<div ng-multi-transclude="panel-left" class="inner-panel"></div>
<div ng-multi-transclude="panel-right" class="inner-panel">middle private content here</div>
<div id="secondPanel" class="inner-panel"></div>
```

and then you can use it like this

```
<div body title="Sample Body Directive">
  <div name="panel-left">
    Public content that goes on the left
  </div>   

  <div name="panel-right">
    Public content that goes on the right
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: thanks buddy. that works. I did not have time to work on that by myself.

Answer (score 2):

As of Angular 1.5 there is support for multiple transclusions without a third party library.

This is referred to as "slot" transclusion and you specify slots by providing an object to the `transclude` property of your directive.

```
directive('someDirective', {
  template: '<div ng-transclude="first"></div><div ng-transclude="second"></div>'
  transclude: {
    first: '?elementOne', // Question mark makes it optional
    second: 'elementTwo'
  },
...
}
```

And then when you use `someDirective`:

```
<some-directive>
  <element-one><!-- content to tranclude into first slot --></element-one>
  <element-two><!-- content to tranclude into second slot --></element-two>
</some-directive>
```

**Additional Reading & Examples**

[Documentation for ngTransclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)

[Using Angular 1.5's Multiple Transclusion Slots](http://www.codelord.net/2016/03/04/using-angular-1-dot-5-s-multiple-transclusion-slots/)